# How do I make cloud-init startup scripts run every time my EC2 instance boots?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, cloud-init

I have an EC2 instance running an AMI based on the Amazon Linux AMI. Like all such AMIs, it supports the [cloud-init](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CloudInit) system for running startup scripts based on the User Data passed into every instance. In this particular case, my User Data input happens to be an Include file that sources several other startup scripts:

```
#include
http://s3.amazonaws.com/path/to/script/1
http://s3.amazonaws.com/path/to/script/2
```

The first time I boot my instance, the cloud-init startup script runs correctly. However, if I do a soft reboot of the instance (by running `sudo shutdown -r now`, for instance), the instance comes back up *without* running the startup script the second time around. If I go into the system logs, I can see:

```
Running cloud-init user-scripts
user-scripts already ran once-per-instance
[  OK  ]
```

This is not what I want -- I can see the utility of having startup scripts that only run once per instance lifetime, but in my case these should run every time the instance starts up, like normal startup scripts.

I realize that one possible solution is to manually have my scripts insert themselves into `rc.local` after running the first time. This seems burdensome, however, since the cloud-init and rc.d environments are subtly different and I would now have to debug scripts on first launch and all subsequent launches separately.

Does anyone know how I can tell cloud-init to always run my scripts? This certainly sounds like something the designers of cloud-init would have considered.

Comment: hey! I copied a bash script file to the /var/lib/cloud/scripts/per-instance folder, however, when I instantiate an instance the script does not get run. Please help

Answer (score 72, accepted):

In 11.10, 12.04 and later, you can achieve this by making the 'scripts-user' run 'always'.
In /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg you'll see something like:

```
cloud_final_modules:
 - rightscale_userdata
 - scripts-per-once
 - scripts-per-boot
 - scripts-per-instance
 - scripts-user
 - keys-to-console
 - phone-home
 - final-message
```

This can be modified after boot, or cloud-config data overriding this stanza can be inserted via user-data.  Ie, in user-data you can provide:

```
#cloud-config
cloud_final_modules:
 - rightscale_userdata
 - scripts-per-once
 - scripts-per-boot
 - scripts-per-instance
 - [scripts-user, always]
 - keys-to-console
 - phone-home
 - final-message
```

That can also be '#included' as you've done in your description.
Unfortunately, right now, you cannot modify the 'cloud_final_modules', but only override it.  I hope to add the ability to modify config sections at some point.

There is a bit more information on this in the cloud-config doc at
https://github.com/canonical/cloud-init/tree/master/doc/examples

Alternatively, you can put files in /var/lib/cloud/scripts/per-boot , and they'll be run by the 'scripts-per-boot' path.

Comment: >  I hope to add the ability to modify config sections at some point.
Has this functionality been added now? I see there is a "merger" feature in the latest cloud-init, but I couldn't figure out how to use that to change only the 'scripts-user' line. It would just override the whole list regardless of the options I passed.

Comment: Here's a one-liner that does the in-line modification: `sed -i 's/scripts-user$/\[scripts-user, always\]/' /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg`

Comment: Put files in `/var/lib/cloud/scripts/per-boot` seems a lot easier, I can use it to setup [auto ec2 shutdown](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38186787/4058484).

Comment: As of 2017, the data has moved elsewhere. Use /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/ and put a new file there.

Comment: @Chetabahana Do you know if that still works? I can't get it to work even after using `sudo chmod a+x run.sh` and `sudo chown root:root run.sh`. EDIT: Actually it will run builtin things but not my own executables no matter what I try. I had to use crontab instead.

Comment: @gumby-the-green It was long time ago but I have noted that not all EC2 types are self recovery on restarting. It might be the case.

Comment: New path to the cloud-init doc examples, now on github: https://github.com/canonical/cloud-init/tree/master/doc/examples

Answer (score 21):

In `/etc/init.d/cloud-init-user-scripts`, edit this line:

```
/usr/bin/cloud-init-run-module once-per-instance user-scripts execute run-parts ${SCRIPT_DIR} >/dev/null && success || failure
```

to

```
 /usr/bin/cloud-init-run-module always user-scripts execute run-parts ${SCRIPT_DIR} >/dev/null && success || failure
```

Good luck !

Answer (score 13):

cloud-init supports this now natively, see runcmd vs bootcmd command descriptions in the documentation (http://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/examples.html#run-commands-on-first-boot):

"runcmd":

```
#cloud-config

# run commands
# default: none
# runcmd contains a list of either lists or a string
# each item will be executed in order at rc.local like level with
# output to the console
# - runcmd only runs during the first boot
# - if the item is a list, the items will be properly executed as if
#   passed to execve(3) (with the first arg as the command).
# - if the item is a string, it will be simply written to the file and
#   will be interpreted by 'sh'
#
# Note, that the list has to be proper yaml, so you have to quote
# any characters yaml would eat (':' can be problematic)
runcmd:
 - [ ls, -l, / ]
 - [ sh, -xc, "echo $(date) ': hello world!'" ]
 - [ sh, -c, echo "=========hello world'=========" ]
 - ls -l /root
 - [ wget, "http://slashdot.org", -O, /tmp/index.html ]
```

"bootcmd":

```
#cloud-config

# boot commands
# default: none
# this is very similar to runcmd, but commands run very early
# in the boot process, only slightly after a 'boothook' would run.
# bootcmd should really only be used for things that could not be
# done later in the boot process.  bootcmd is very much like
# boothook, but possibly with more friendly.
# - bootcmd will run on every boot
# - the INSTANCE_ID variable will be set to the current instance id.
# - you can use 'cloud-init-per' command to help only run once
bootcmd:
 - echo 192.168.1.130 us.archive.ubuntu.com >> /etc/hosts
 - [ cloud-init-per, once, mymkfs, mkfs, /dev/vdb ]
```

also note the "cloud-init-per" command example in bootcmd. From it's help:

```
Usage: cloud-init-per frequency name cmd [ arg1 [ arg2 [ ... ] ]
   run cmd with arguments provided.

   This utility can make it easier to use boothooks or bootcmd
   on a per "once" or "always" basis.

   If frequency is:
      * once: run only once (do not re-run for new instance-id)
      * instance: run only the first boot for a given instance-id
      * always: run every boot
```

Comment: update answer with corresponding citations from official documentation and linked to original documentation for reference only

Comment: The bootcmd part is executed on a system that is not fully booted and might not work as expected.

Comment: How do you use cloud-init-per in ec2 UserData to run cfn-init script on each boot?

Answer (score 8):

One possibility, although somewhat hackish, is to delete the lock file that cloud-init uses to determine whether or not the user-script has already run. In my case (Amazon Linux AMI), this lock file is located in `/var/lib/cloud/sem/` and is named `user-scripts.i-7f3f1d11` (the hash part at the end changes every boot). Therefore, the following user-data script added to the end of the Include file will do the trick:

```
#!/bin/sh
rm /var/lib/cloud/sem/user-scripts.*
```

I'm not sure if this will have any adverse effects on anything else, but it has worked in my experiments.

Comment: "the hash part" seems to be an amazon machine id ¿isn't?

Comment: It looks like an AWS instance ID, in which case it would change with each instance launch, but stay the same across stops and restarts of the same instance.

Comment: for me /var/lib/cloud/sem/ did not contain anything useful, however removing the following semaphores worked: `sudo rm /var/lib/cloud/instance/sem/config_write_files` and 
`sudo rm /var/lib/cloud/instance/sem/config_runcmd`

Answer (score 3):

I struggled with this issue for almost two days, tried all of the solutions I could find and finally, combining several approaches, came up with the following:

```
MyResource:
  Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
  Metadata:
    AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
      configSets:
        setup_process:
          - "prepare"
          - "run_for_instance"
      prepare:
        commands:
          01_apt_update:
            command: "apt-get update"
          02_clone_project:
            command: "mkdir -p /replication && rm -rf /replication/* && git clone https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-cross-region-library.git /replication/dynamodb-cross-region-library/"
          03_build_project:
            command: "mvn install -DskipTests=true"
            cwd: "/replication/dynamodb-cross-region-library"
          04_prepare_for_apac:
            command: "mkdir -p /replication/replication-west && rm -rf /replication/replication-west/* && cp /replication/dynamodb-cross-region-library/target/dynamodb-cross-region-replication-1.2.1.jar /replication/replication-west/replication-runner.jar"
      run_for_instance:
        commands:
          01_run:
            command: !Sub "java -jar replication-runner.jar --sourceRegion us-east-1 --sourceTable ${TableName} --destinationRegion ap-southeast-1 --destinationTable ${TableName} --taskName -us-ap >/dev/null 2>&1 &"
            cwd: "/replication/replication-west"
  Properties:
    UserData:
      Fn::Base64:
        !Sub |
          #cloud-config
          cloud_final_modules:
           - [scripts-user, always]
          runcmd:
           - /usr/local/bin/cfn-init -v -c setup_process --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource MyResource --region ${AWS::Region}
           - /usr/local/bin/cfn-signal -e $? --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource MyResource --region ${AWS::Region}
```

This is the setup for DynamoDb cross-region replication process.

Comment: You said you "combined many approaches". Can you please elaborate which items from your above cfn helped with getting your userdata scripts to run on every startup? Thanks.

Comment: @CBP,  basically,  `AWS::CloudFormation::Init` will run the code on each startup . And `run_for_instance` step will run the replication script

Comment: what is the difference between prepare and run_for_instance? are both runing on every setup?

Comment: Yes. It's just for clear separation sake. Think of it as of two different methods.

Answer (score 3):

If someone wants to do this on CDK, here's a python example.

For Windows, user data has a special [`persist` tag](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-windows-user-data.html#user-data-execution), but for Linux, you need to use [MultiPart User data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-ec2-readme.html#multipart-user-data) to setup cloud-init first. This Linux example worked with `cloud-config` (see [ref blog](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/execute-user-data-ec2/)) part type instead of [`cloud-boothook`](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html#bootcmd) which requires a `cloud-init-per` (see also [bootcmd](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html#bootcmd)) call I couldn't test out (eg: `cloud-init-pre always`).

Linux example:

```
    # Create some userdata commands
    instance_userdata = ec2.UserData.for_linux()
    instance_userdata.add_commands("apt update")
    # ...
    # Now create the first part to make cloud-init run it always
    cinit_conf = ec2.UserData.for_linux();
    cinit_conf .add_commands('#cloud-config');
    cinit_conf .add_commands('cloud_final_modules:');
    cinit_conf .add_commands('- [scripts-user, always]');
    multipart_ud = ec2.MultipartUserData()
    #### Setup to run every time instance starts
    multipart_ud.add_part(ec2.MultipartBody.from_user_data(cinit_conf , content_type='text/cloud-config'))
    #### Add the commands desired to run every time
    multipart_ud.add_part(ec2.MultipartBody.from_user_data(instance_userdata));

    ec2.Instance(
        self, "myec2",
        userdata=multipart_ud,
        #other required config...
    )
```

Windows example:

```
    instance_userdata = ec2.UserData.for_windows()
    # Bootstrap
    instance_userdata.add_commands("Write-Output 'Run some commands'")
    # ...
    # Making all the commands persistent - ie: running on each instance start
    data_script = instance_userdata.render()
    data_script += "<persist>true</persist>"
    ud = ec2.UserData.custom(data_script)
    ec2.Instance(
        self, "myWinec2",
        userdata=ud,
        #other required config...
    )
```

Comment: I used the similar approach and saw that the user data commands script has been run twice. Did you encounter this?

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to use `#cloud-boothook` in your user data script. From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/amazon-linux-ami-basics.html#amazon-linux-cloud-init):

> Cloud Boothook
>
> - Begins with #cloud-boothook or Content-Type: text/cloud-boothook.
> - This content is boothook data. It is stored in a file under /var/lib/cloud and then executed immediately.
> - This is the earliest "hook" available. **There is no mechanism provided for running it only one time.** The boothook must take care
>     of this itself. It is provided with the instance ID in the environment
>     variable INSTANCE_ID. Use this variable to provide a once-per-instance
>     set of boothook data.

Answer (score 1):

please use the below script above your bash script.

example: here m printing hello world to my file

stop instance before adding to userdata

### script

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="//"
MIME-Version: 1.0

--//
Content-Type: text/cloud-config; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="cloud-config.txt"

#cloud-config
cloud_final_modules:
- [scripts-user, always]

--//
Content-Type: text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="userdata.txt"

#!/bin/bash
/bin/echo "Hello World." >> /var/tmp/sdksdfjsdlf
--//
```

Comment: don't copy paste from aws docs add some explanation

Comment: ```x-shellscript-per-boot``` is key like:

```cloud-init devel make-mime -a always.sh:x-shellscript-per-boot -a instance.sh:x-shellscript-per-instance -a once.sh:x-shellscript-per-once```

copied from 
https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/explanation/format.html#examples

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me on Amazon Linux 2 was removing semaphores under `/var/lib/cloud/instance/sem/`:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/cloud/instance/sem/config_write_files
sudo rm /var/lib/cloud/instance/sem/config_runcmd
sudo rm /var/lib/cloud/instance/sem/config_scripts_user
```

In theory one could create a cron to remove these files periodically