# Cloud-init per-boot script doing nothing

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, cloud-init

I am new to cloud-init, my final goal is to run an R script each time an EC2 Spot Instance becomes active, but in order to test it I created an on-demand Ubuntu 12.04 instance and created a simple script but nothing happens after reboot. Here are the steps I took:

- Launched the new Ubunut 12.04 instance
- Navigate to `/var/lib/cloud/scripts/per-boot`
- `sudo vi script.sh`
- Added the following code:

> #!/bin/sh
>   echo "test"

- `sudo reboot`

At this point I thought I should see a "test" print when the instance reboots, but there is nothing there. I went to take a look at `/var/log/cloud-init.log` but there is no error or anything out of the ordinary.

I am clearly missing something so any tip in the right direction will be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: I finally managed to do this using `rc.local`, this doesn't answer my original question as I still don't know why the script was not loading, but it might help someone in the same situation as mine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't run unless the scripts user is set to always run. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10455027/877115) for more details (and for instructions on how to get scripts to run on reboot, generally).

Comment: Is this correct? This question is about `/var/lib/cloud/scripts/per-boot/*` and the question you link to is about getting `/var/lib/cloud/instance/user-data.txt` to run on every boot. The last statement in the answer suggests using the former in place of the later.

Answer (score 9):

Looked at the [source code](https://github.com/canonical/cloud-init/blob/93cebe009d116230850c770227e9ead5c490c0d0/cloudinit/subp.py#L375), the script must be executable. This'll make it work

`sudo chmod 744 script.sh`

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer is not adequate imo, so after I spent my whole morning getting to the bottom of this I will write my view since I believe people will find this useful and save time.

If the `scripts-user` module is set to always run then the `runcmd:` section of your cloudinit will run at every boot.

This can be done with by adding the following section on your cloud-config file,

```
cloud_final_modules:
 - [scripts-user, always]
```

If you want to run certain **scripts at every boot** then you need to place under the

`/var/lib/cloud/scripts/per-boot/` folder. To achieve that, add the following section to your cloud-config file,

```
write_files:
  - content: |
      #!/bin/bash
      echo "Hello World.  The time is now $(date -R)!"
    path: /var/lib/cloud/scripts/per-boot/myScript.sh
    permissions: "0755"
```

Now everytime I reboot my EC2 instance it will run `myScript.sh`

And a full example of `cloud-config` that installs amazon ssm agent on Rhel 8

```
#cloud-config
cloud_final_modules:
 - rightscale_userdata
 - scripts-per-once
 - scripts-per-boot
 - scripts-per-instance
 - scripts-user
 - keys-to-console
 - phone-home
 - final-message

write_files:
  - content: |
      #!/bin/bash
      echo "Hello World.  The time is now $(date -R)!"
    path: /var/lib/cloud/scripts/per-boot/myScript.sh
    permissions: "0755"


runcmd:
  - sudo dnf install -y python3
  - sudo yum install -y https://s3.amazonaws.com/ec2-downloads-windows/SSMAgent/latest/linux_amd64/amazon-ssm-agent.rpm
  - sudo systemctl enable amazon-ssm-agent
  - sudo systemctl start amazon-ssm-agent
```

Please note that in this case `myScript.sh` precedes the execution of `runcmd:` on first boot and subsequent boots only execute `myScript.sh`

Comment: Well, all very interesting, but surely a better answer would be rc.d/cron/whatever. I can't immediately see any use whatever for a cloud-init per-boot script. Is there one?

Answer (score 5):

If we want to debug the user-data in cloud-init, we can try the following steps:

1. rm -rf /var/lib/cloud/*
2. cloud-init init
3. cloud-init modules -m final

With above commands, the cloud-init is re-run. And we can check the cloud-init.log under /var/log/cloud-init.log to check if it is successfully exec.

Comment: After doing this once I was getting an error `IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/var/lib/cloud/instance'` on repeat runs of the module. I didn't want to lose/recreate my `/var/lib/cloud/scripts/per-boot` scripts so I experimented and found that `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/cloud/instance /var/lib/cloud/instances/*; sudo cloud-init modules -m final` is the minimal cleanup needed to allow me to retest. Thanks for the lead!