# Cloud-init per-boot scripts in cloud/scripts/per-boot

Tags: cloud-init

I am trying to put my script file (script.sh) in the /var/lib/cloud/scripts/per-boot/ directory, so that the cloud-init runs the script every time my VPS boots.

But the problem is the script is not getting executed when the VPS boots. Not even once.

My script file goes like this(this is just a test file)...

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Hello User !!!"
mkdir /tmp/test
```

Is there any mistake I am doing ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Is your script executable? It won't run if it's not executable. Also, one part of the cloud-init documentation says not to write to `/tmp`. `per-boot` scripts run after `runcmd` but it might be possible the same issue is possible during `per-boot` scripts as well. https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html?highlight=%2Fvar%2Ftmp#runcmd

Comment: Hello, Sorry for the delay in replying, as you said the script file was executable  already and also I have edited the script file to make a new demo file( /home/user/user.txt ) in home directory from previous (/tmp/test) dir. But the Cloud-Init is still not able to process my per-boot script even after rebooting. Any other suggestions?? Thanks for Your reply!

Comment: Any luck with this? Im having the same problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cloud-init per-boot script doing nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240194/cloud-init-per-boot-script-doing-nothing)