# Load user data on every boot up of EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, user-data

I am having AWS EC2 instance.

I want to load user data on every boot up of EC2 instance.

Whether this is possible or i have to create new instance each time to execute user data?

Comment: user-data is just static metadata attached to an instance--it's always available, even across reboots.  I suspect that your question is more in regards to `cloud-init`, which reads in the user-data value and bootstraps the instance.  If that's the case, then your question is a duplicate of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475374/how-do-i-make-cloud-init-startup-scripts-run-every-time-my-ec2-instance-boots

Answer (score 1):

Multiple options:

- create a custom AMI with the users and co figurations you want. Easiest way to do this is to create an EBS backed instance, do the setup, and the. Select the dashboard option to create an AMI from the instance.
- have your settings on a remote source(s3 for instance), which your instance is setup to pull and execute/add/configure.

For a single instance, the AMI works well. For a larger environment, configs management like kickstart, puppet, chef, cfengine, or similar will be better.