# Running script in already existing EC2 instance

Tags: shell, amazon-ec2

Is there any way to run user defined script in already launched EC2 Instance?
I have already tried by first calling modifyInstanceAttribute() to modify the user data
and then starting the instance,but it is not working.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

By default, user data is run only once during instance initialization. If you want to run it all the time, during instance reboot, you should change cloudinit configuration.

Check this question:
[How do I make cloud-init startup scripts run every time my EC2 instance boots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475374/how-do-i-make-cloud-init-startup-scripts-run-every-time-my-ec2-instance-boots)

Comment: Actually I have not worked on cloud-init.I am giving the script file content in user data section while launching the instance.
Can you please help me regarding how to use cloud-init for running scripts.

Comment: User data is run by cloud-init. Basically AWS is sending user-data to cloud-init (if we are talking about Linux machines) or 'I forgot it's name', for Windows. For more info on this you can check AWS docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AESDG-chapter-instancedata.html#instancedata-user-data-retrieval and cloud-init docs: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CloudInit.