# run shell script on every restart of ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have followed [ec2 run scripts every boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43056007/ec2-run-scripts-every-boot) and tried the same approach for per-instance but my script still doesn't get executed.

I also followed [Execute User Data After the Initial Launch of Your EC2 Instance](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/execute-user-data-ec2/) and yet the script doesn't get executed. Content of the script:

```
nohup /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/bin/python3 -u medi_app.py &> nohup_medi &
```

Why is it proving so hard to run a script every time an instance restarts? Can someone please help out here?

Comment: Have you considered native OS features, such as an [@reboot cron task](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-execute-cron-job-after-system-reboot/)?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using an Amazon EC2 Linux instance to run a batch job on startup, simply install the script in this directory:

```
/var/lib/cloud/scripts/per-boot/
```

This will work on any system that has [cloud-init](https://cloud-init.io/) installed, which also runs User Data scripts.

For more details, see: [Auto-Stop EC2 instances when they finish a task - DEV Community](https://dev.to/aws/auto-stop-ec2-instances-when-they-finish-a-task-2f0i)