# Script execution using userdata in AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, devops

Need to run scripts  in user data  on specific instance behaivor, like example:

"In my script there are certain portion that's need to be run  on initial launch of instance and don't execute this script on reboot or start state"

"The other part of script should execute on initial launch and on reboot or started state"

Is that possible ?

Comment: Related: [amazon ec2 - How do I make cloud-init startup scripts run every time my EC2 instance boots? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475374/how-do-i-make-cloud-init-startup-scripts-run-every-time-my-ec2-instance-boots)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thank you :)

Comment: Use the part of your script that should only once as the init-script. Also, in the init-script, add a init.d script that should run on every reboot.